# Understanding adversarial Channels

Tags: error-correction, quantum-operation, information-theory

The paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0605086.pdf) (Definition 1) defines adversarial channels as $N(\rho)= \sum_i A_i \rho A_i$ with the mention that the $A_i$ is chosen only after a communication strategy is decide. This gives the definition of `general' adversarial channel.

I guess that I can define them in the following way:
$$ N(\rho) = \sum_{i} \alpha_i P_i \rho P_i$$ where where $P_i$ are elements of Pauli group.

Does that seem correct?
Is there a notion of adversarial Pauli Channels introduced in the literature?

Comment: I don't understand where you're saying the cross terms $P_1 \rho P_2$ should come from. Are you asking what an "adversarial Pauli channel" is, or are you defining it?

Comment: @glS I am asking what an ``adversarial Pauli channel is. The expression written above was an attempt to define one. I have removed the line about cross terms, but it was just to highlight the difference (according to my proposed  definition) between the family of adversarial channels and the family of adversarial Pauli channels. The general family can have cross terms (with non-zero $\alpha$) where as adversarial Pauli Channels don't. If there is already a standard definition for adversarial Pauli channels, I would be happy with that as well.